# Jenkins Terraform Pipeline failed to refresh cached credentials, no EC2 IMDS role found

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, terraform-provider-aws

While doing terraform configuration changes at local windows 11 environment it working properly, but intgrating with jenkins pipeline at linux environment giving below error.

> Error: No valid credential sources found[0m
> Please see https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/s3.html
> for more information about providing credentials.
> Error: failed to refresh cached credentials, no EC2 IMDS role found,
> operation error ec2imds: GetMetadata, http response error StatusCode: 404,
> request to EC2 IMDS failed.

I updated aws credential,terraform configuration & git checkout on linux environment.

- `terraform local/windows environment`: Terraform v1.7.3 on windows_amd64
- `terraform linux environment`: Terraform v1.6.5 on linux_386
- `terraform provider`: provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v5.40.0
- Terraform code repo: https://github.com/clouddevaws1961/Terraform

Comment: Verify AWS Credentials, IAM Roles, and Policies. Then check network configuration with internet access to reach the EC2 IMDS service. And you can post the relevant terraform code here.

Comment: Can you make sure you are doing the tests from the Jenkins instance you refer in the question title? Doing things locally does not really help with the issue you're facing, or vice versa.

Comment: issue has been resolved . need  to update aws credential propely inside Jenkins   so installed Steps AWS credential plugin for secretId and secretkey

Answer (score 1):

make sure you're using same profile name which usually exists at ~/.aws directory, if you did state locking with s3 and dynamodb make sure the profile configured in it (e.g: backend.tf) is the same as the profile name configured in your main.tf or providers.tf.

Lastly if nothing worked for you, try to change the profile name to default and just remove the profile definition from your terraform configuration.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).